# is that parseFloat(string).tofixed(2) will cause me a problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some data like RM 28.51 (Currency), RM30.28(Currency) in my table
and need to use these data to do some calculation

my solution is to parseFloat(28.51).tofixed(2) + parseFloat(30.28).tofixed(2)

but when the moment more and more data come in , sometimes they will some decimal point error
shown as result

Example my result at the end will show 3859.39
but the actual is 3859.40

Is there any better solution?

Comment: `parseFloat(28.51).tofixed(2) + parseFloat(30.28).tofixed(2)` - this won't add the numbers because `.toFixed()` returns a string. Also why do you call `parseFloat()` with numbers?

Comment: The more single rounded numbers you add the bigger the loss of data becomes. If table refers to an actual database, I recommend to do your calculations on it as well.

Comment: above is some example, sometimes the data is string.
so as @Lain mention, I cant use parseFloat.toFixed right

Comment: or should I use
Math.round(someNumber * 1e2) / 1e2
instead of 

var someNumber = 123.456;
someNumber = parseFloat(someNumber.toFixed(2));

Comment: One ancient way used to be a multiplication to whole numbers and division back to decimals. Like `(parseFloat('28.51')*1000 + parseFloat('30.28')*1000)/1000`.

Comment: You should not use floating-point number if you want to represent decimals: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `parseFloat(28.51).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(30.28).toFixed(2)` - sometimes they will some decimal point error shown as result

The JavaScript [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method **takes in a number and outputs a string**

When you use `+` with two numbers, you **add** both numbers.

When you use `+` with two strings, you **join** both strings together.

The example below illustrates the difference.

```js
function addTwoStrings(value1, value2) {
  return parseFloat(value1).toFixed(2) + parseFloat(value2).toFixed(2)
}
function addTwoNumbers(value1, value2) {
  return (parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)).toFixed(2)
}

console.log(addTwoStrings(28.514, 30.284))
console.log(addTwoNumbers(28.514, 30.284))
```

Comment: I think OP's problem is more to do with floating point precision in JavaScript.

Comment: @phuzi Oops read *that* wrong

Comment: ```const value1 = 28.51
const value2 = '30.28'
const value3 = +value1 + +value2


function valueToCurrencyString(value) {
   return parseFloat(value).toLocaleString('en', {
     minimumFractionDigits: 2,
     maximumFractionDigits: 2,
     style: 'currency',
     currency: 'MYR'
   });
}

console.log(valueToCurrencyString(value3));

newNumber = parseFloat(value3).toFixed(2);
console.log(newNumber);
```
sorry am a newbie, but is that newNumber any dffirence with console.log(valueToCurrencyString(value3));

Comment: Sorry @HongErnest I don't understand that question

Comment: ohh sorry, I means
If I parseFloat(value3).toFixed(2), what is the difference to
console.log(valueToCurrencyString(value3));

Comment: @HongErnest I have massively improved the answer please take another read :)